# Node.js converting async into promise

Tags: node.js, q

I have a middleware function which hits an api and returns an ID. This works correctly, but calls next before it returns with the Data. The view is rendered without the data the first time around. I'd prefer to wrap this in a promise and update the view when it is available. What would be the best way to implement this. I've been working with implementing something with the Q service but haven't had any luck.

Server.js

```
var app        = express();
var guid       = require('./server/guid.js')(app);

app.use(guid.checkGUID);
```

guid.js

```
var express    = require('express');
var Q          = require('q');
var request    = require('request');
var uuid       = require('uuid');

module.exports = function(app){


var checkGUID = function(req, res, next) {
  if(!app.locals.guid){
    getGUID();
    next();
  }else{
    next();
  }
};

var getGUIDOptions = {
  options....
};

var getGUID = function(req,res, next) {
  request(getGUIDOptions, returnGUID);  
};

function returnGUID(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    app.locals.guid = body.guid;
    return body.guid;
  }else{
    console.log(body);
  }
};

return {
        checkGUID: checkGUID
    } 
}
```

Comment: Err..your getGUID() requires three args but you call it with none. Is this intentional? As you've written it, the next() callback for the checkGUID middleware will never be called, which will cause the request to timeout without resolution.

Comment: The reason your handler is calling next before you can retrieve a new GUID is because you told it to. ;)  Remember, nothing in Node waits. Everything executes as the statement is encountered, so in your code getGUID() is called and then next() is called.  (Node.js - one thread, no waiting! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Promises, you only need to call the middleware next() callback for the request. Here's how I'd write it, note that I try to handle all expected error conditions correctly.

```
var util=require('util'),
    request = require('request');

module.exports = function(app) {

  /**
   * Assure we have an app-wide GUID
   * @param {object} req
   * @param {object} res
   * @param {function} next - callback to next stage in request processing
   */
  var assureGUID = function(req, res, next) {
    if(app.locals.guid){ // we already have one
      next();
      return;
    }
    getGUID(req, res, next);
  };

  /**
   * Retrieve a GUID for this app
   * @param {object} req
   * @param {object} res
   * @param {function} next - callback to next stage in request processing
   */
  var getGUID = function(req, res, next) {

    var getGUIDOptions = {
      //options....
    };

    request(getGUIDOptions, function(err,resp,body){
      if(err){
        next(err);
        return;
      }
      if(200 !== resp.statusCode){
        next(new Error('failed to retrieve GUID, status='+resp.statusCode));
        return;
      }
      if(!('object'===typeof body && 'string'===typeof body.guid && body.guid)){
        next(new Error('failed to retrieve GUID, resp: '+util.inspect(resp,{depth:null})));
        return;
      }

      app.locals.guid=body.guid;

      next();
    });
  };

  return {
    assureGUID: assureGUID
  }
};
```

In essence, when the request hits this handler and we already have a GUID for this app, we press on (by calling next()). If we don't already have a GUID, a request is made for a new GUID and when we have it, we call next().

If you're dead-set on using Promises, I'd be happy to append that solution as well.

#### UPDATE

Ok, here's the promised(sic) Promises version. I (and many others) prefer Petka Antonov's [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) Promises implementation so I will use that here instead of `Q` which, if required, you should be able to convert this code to without much trouble.

```
// Promises version

var util=require('util'),
    Promise=require('bluebird'),
    request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request')); // see note 1.

var assureGUID = function(req,res,next){

  if(app.locals.guid){ // we already have one
    next();
    return;
  }

  var getGUIDOptions = {
    //options....
  };

  request.get(getGUIDOptions) // see note 2.
      .catch(function(err){ // get request failed
        next(new Error('GET request for GUID failed:'+err));
      })
      .spread(function(resp,body){ // see note 3.
        // check for proper result
        if(200 !== resp.statusCode){
          throw new Error('failed to retrieve GUID, status='+resp.statusCode);
        }
        if(!('object'===typeof body && 'string'===typeof body.guid && body.guid)){
          throw new Error('failed to retrieve GUID, resp: '+util.inspect(resp,{depth:null}));
        }
        app.locals.guid=body.guid;
        next();
      })
      .catch(function(err){ // unexpected result
        next(err);
      });
};
```

A few notes:

1. `Promise.promisifyAll()` will *automagically* convert all functions exposed by the `request` module into Promises if they follow the standard `f(err,res)` Node callback pattern.
2. See the notes regarding "promisification" at [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for why we need to use `request.get()` rather than simply `request()`.
3. If the call does not support `f(err,res)`, you can use `Promise.spread()` to "spread" the available arguments from the base function. So, since `request.get()` is called with three args: `err` (consumed by the Promise), `res` and `body`, we need to "spread" the remaining two args into the new Promise callback.

Finally, while I have not tested this code, it should work. If you have any issues with it, please don't hesitate to add further comments.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response! That makes a lot of sense. If you could append a promises solution that would be very helpful as well.